# Options for impact sensors?

Tags: sensor, strain-gage

I'm looking for a sensor to sense impact, let's say the sensor is placed behind a thick metal/wood casing, the impact depending on the amount of force could either deform the casing or only causes vibrations. Every path have led me to strain gauge sensors and I was wondering if these types of sensors can sense a force that only cause vibrations ? I am not interested in calculating the force but only a sensor that's triggered by a force, is there a better option than strain gauge ? how much surface do one strain gauge sensor normally cover in terms of sensing ?

Comment: A Vibration sensor. aka a contact microphone

Comment: [A Shock Sensor](https://www.texe.com/uk/products/series/perimeter-detectors/impaq-s-series/) . These use an accelerometer.

Comment: Thanks, Piezo Sensors looks like the best option.

Comment: Perhaps even a low-travel tactile switch, if the deformation could exceed the travel limit of the switch?  This could be a very low-cost approach.